# jQuery modal video js plugin

Tags: jquery, html, video, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use a JQuery plugin and everything works except the video does not load and I can't figure out why. I have a vimeo video that I want to display on my site with a model video player. This is the [plugin](https://appleple.github.io/modal-video/)

Here is my code:

```
<script src = "Scripts/modal-video.js"></script>
<button class="js-modal-btn" data-video-id="217038687">Open Vimeo</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".js-modal-btn").modalVideo({channel:'vimeo'});
 });
</script>
```

This is what I see when I click example button [Modal View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atiQN.png).

I also get this error on page source file://player.vimeo.com/video/217038687?api=false&autopause=true&autoplay=true&byline=true&loop=false&portrait=true&title=true&xhtml=falseFailed to load resource: 
**The requested URL was not found on this server.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the error references `file://` would lead me to think that you're missing the protocol on the href of your embed but you haven't provided this in your example.

Comment: So what protocol should I include? Can you show it here.